# Recently used documents are not actualized during a KDE session

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, plasma

I use Kubuntu 16.04 LTS. After opening a document during my KDE session a link appears immediately under `~/.local/share/RecentDocuments` but nothing appears under the "Recent documents" entry of the Plasma widgets "Applications menu" and Kickoff. Plasma needs a restart to show the new entry. Is this a feature? Is there a way to for Plasma to show immediately new recent documents (without restarting Plasma)?

Comment: I just noticed that `~/.local/share/RecentDocuments` does not cover all the recent documents shown by Plasma. There must be another place where Plasma stores recent documents but I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps because there is also a `.kde/share/apps/RecentDocuments`. You can try symlinking them as described [here](https://github.com/netrunner-kubuntu/netrunner-default-settings/blob/master/etc/skel/.config/plasma-workspace/env/recentdoc_fix.sh):

```
 ln -sf ~/.local/share/RecentDocuments ~/.kde/share/apps/RecentDocuments
```